# TexShop diacritic encoding

Tags: texshop, input-encodings

A newbie question.

I have a number of colleagues who always use a different editor rather than texshop to edit, but use texshop to compile nonetheless. The reason I was told is that texshop corrupt the encoding. Is there a way to overcome that?

Whenever I have a tex file with diacritics in UTF8-encoding, texshop will show the diacritics properly but will corrupt it if I save it again even though I have UTF8-encoding in preference.

A minimal example:
ā

Viewed from another editor:
\UTF{0101}%

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that `TeXShop->Preferences->Misc->pTeX support->utf export` preference is off (unchecked). When on, it instructs TexShop to export the unicode characters as `\UTF(Hex code)` thus allowing PTex (Japanese typesetting) extended support for UTF characters.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed I need to work with Japanese, Chinese and Sanskrit characters. I disabled the option and now I can do everything on TexShop, even with the Japanese!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default encoding for TeXShop to Unicode(UTF-8) in the Preferences->Source->Encoding popup menu item.

Alternatively, if you use multiple encodings for different files, place the line

% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

near the top of the Source file. TeXShop will read that line and read/write the file with that encoding.

Good Luck,

Herb Schulz