# Rendering a unicode en-dash in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode

If I am understanding things correctly, using XeLaTeX, all of these lines should be output with proper em- and en- dashes respectively:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}

Hello---world!

Hello—world!

Hello--world!

Hello–world!

\end{document}
```

However, no matter what font I choose I receive an error with the unicode en-dash (the em-dash works fine as does the `--` sequence to generate the en-dash):

```
 ./dash-testing.te.tex:13: Undefined control sequence. 
 l.13 Hello\UTF
               {2013}world! \\
```

But I can see, using InDesign glyph viewer or other, that character 2013 does indeed exist. And direct input of other characters, like `“` and others is working.

How can I get the unicode en-dash to work?

Updated: this is the output I get if I continue the compilation (just to demonstrate that the proper font is indeed being used).

[image: bad en dash, bad]

Comment: Works for me if I substitute `\setmainfont{GentiumPlus-R.ttf}`.  (Though my system doesn't find the font at all if I use your `\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}`.)

Comment: That doesn't change anything for me...with either statement, Gentium Plus is being found. And I've tried with multiple other fonts that I know have the en-dash and same problem!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was nonexistent

Answer (score 0):

I copied your complete from my browser into a new text file and compiled it with xelatex and worked without any problems. **I see absolutely no reason why your code should not work**

- Try to make a complete new file in a new directory after having closed any console windows or probably having restarted your computer.

  *This helps sometimes when I have similiar problems...*
- If this does not help, try updating your TeX-distribution

[image: em-dashes at work]

Answer (score 0):

Gentium is also available as a Type 1 font, e.g. in `TEXMF/fonts/type1/public/gentium-tug/` I suppose that you also have this font installed and XeLaTeX
uses the first one which is found. However, you can force XeLaTeX to use the TrueType version with:

```
\setmainfont[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*-R,
  ItalicFont=*-I]{GentiumPlus}
```

> This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)
>   (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.2.13)  14 FEB 2016 20:43

```
 fontspec-xetex.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

Comment: No. I installed Gentium specifically for this purpose (and as noted above, specifying the .ttf as an earlier person proposed or the way you have shown) doesn't change the error message. I've also tried with Arial Unicode MS, Hoefler Text and a variety of fonts, some also installed just for troubleshooting.

Comment: what TeX distribution do you have. Important is also the version of fontspec. Se my edit

Comment: `xelatex --version` results in: `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)` and `tlmgr` gives this info for fontspec: `cat-version: 2.5a
cat-date:    2016-02-01 14:28:29 +0100`

Comment: Then you have already the Gentium fonts installed in `TEXMF/fonts/truetype/public/gentium-tug/`  and you should use that ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry to have wasted your time. This turns out to be a TexShop "problem." I didn't realize, until I was editing the test files in Vim, that TexShop wasn't showing me the exact source. Until I used Vim I couldn't see that where I saw an `–` the actual source literally had `UTF{2013}`.

This is a preference for supporting pTeX, fixed by turning that preference off as in this StackExchange answer: [TexShop diacritic encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193872/texshop-diacritic-encoding)